# How to make a tumblr style profile url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I wonder, how does tumblr doing profile url like this:

```
http://www.username.tumblr.com/ 
http://username.tumblr.com/
```

I know we can change the profile url

```
http://www.website.com/profile.php?user=username
```

to

```
http://www.website.com/username
```

using the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I don't know how tumblr doing those profile urls.

How can we make user profile urls like this:

```
http://www.username.website.com/
http://username.website.com/
```

I have a VirtualHost.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840724/subdomain-for-each-user

Comment: Yet another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408582/virtual-subdomain-one-subdomain-per-user

Comment: Still more duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116898/how-do-i-create-personal-sub-domain-programmatically-with-php

Comment: And more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841006/create-subdomain-upon-user-registration

Answer (score 7):

Key solution: **wildcard subdomains**.

This allows you to make `*.domain.com` point to your server.

From your example, let's say we enabled wildcard subdomains for `domain.com` and we want to provide user subdomains, such as `http://username.domain.com`. You'd have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

where `http://username.domain.com/xxx` would point to `/username/xxx`.

Note that this example has been reduced and simplified as much as possible for the explanation. You'd maybe need other rules, depending on your context, to handle main domain and other conditions.